# Can't change non admin password with RDWeb

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, rdweb

I setup RDWeb on my Windows Server 2012 R2 installation to allow domain users to change their own password. However only Administrator users can change their password. When a regular user wants to change their password is says:

> Your new password does not meet the length, complexity, or history requirements of your domain. Try choosing a different new password.

However, the entered password is fine. When I add the user to the Administrator group I can change the password just fine.

What is causing this?

Comment: see if administrators are in the " “Security Filtering” list , in the GPO, only groups in this list are enforced to use the strong passwords, I think you are only enforcing it to non admins, check Default Domain policy for Computer Configuration -> Policies -> Windows Settings -> Security Settings -> Account Policies -> Password Policy and disable  "Passwords Must Meet Complexity Requirements" if you want it like that.

Comment: I found the settings and immediately saw the problem. The default setting for minimum password age is 1 day. I tried to change the password immediately after adding the user.